# I am new to the Laravel. I got this project and I don't know why this is not displaying pictures

Tags: laravel, image, broken-links, broken-image

Things I tried
1.simple path without URL::to
2.url() method
3.absolute path
4.asset(simple relative path)
in my .env file changed APP_URL from http://localhost to http://localhost:8000 since it runs on 8000 port
I am adding some pictures.
One thing which is important to mention here when i use Simple relative path it shows picture on hovering the mouse in IDE and on browser too but browser does not render it on webpage.
Please [`see pictures`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuMbJ.png)

src="{{URL::to('public/imgs/2.png')}}"

Comment: try this `src="{{ asset('imgs/2.png') }}"`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but because Its not my project I am supposed to modify it, and it included public in the image path so I never tried without this. The important thing is it worked.

Comment: for all the assets we use `asset()` in laravel old versions when `asset()` helper was not there that time people use to do like your code

Comment: storage/app/products now pictures in this folder are not showing up <img src="{{URL::to('storage/app/products/')}}/{{$featuredProducts[0]->image}}" style="width:100%;max-height:230px;border:2px solid #034375"> this is how its being rendered in the project I got from database but its not working

Comment: try `{{ \Storage::url($featuredProducts[0]->image) }}` as it is stored in storage folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your image resource files in public folder then access those resources through the following way:

```
    src="{{ URL::asset('imgs/2.png') }}"
```

Comment: storage/app/products  now pictures in this folder are not showing up                                        <img src="{{URL::to('storage/app/products/')}}/{{$featuredProducts[0]->image}}" style="width:100%;max-height:230px;border:2px solid #034375"> this is how its being rendered in the project I got from database but its not working

Comment: you have to put your image file in public folder inside storage as: storage/app/public/products and access it {{URL::to('storage/products/')}}/{{$featuredProducts[0]->image}}

Comment: refer to this link for more information: 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/show-images-from-storage-folder